# AsyncTask generates two notifications

Tags: android, android-asynctask, notifications

I am downloading a video from server.I am displaying the progress of the download in notification.As soon as the download completes,i show Download Complete in my notification,but the notification displaying progress is also seen.How to get rid of the notification showing progress,once download is complete.Here is my code

```
 public class VideoAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                    getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentText("Download in progress")
                    // .setContentIntent(contentIntent(getApplicationContext()))
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, 0, false);

            notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, values[0], false);
            notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {

    try {

        URL url = new URL(params[0].toString());
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.connect();


        String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File file = new File(PATH + "/SavedVideos");
        try {
            file.mkdirs();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        if (!contacts.getVideoName().contains(".mp4")) {
            contacts.getVideoName().concat(".mp4");
        }


        File outputFile = new File(file, contacts.getVideoName());
        if (!outputFile.exists()) {
            outputFile.createNewFile();
        }


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;
        publishProgress(Math.min(buffer.length, 100));
        while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {

            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        }
        fos.close();
        is.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  /*  for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 5) {
        // Sets the progress indicator completion percentage
        publishProgress(Math.min(i, 100));
        try {
            // Sleep for 5 seconds
            Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d("Failure", "sleeping failure");
        }
    }*/


    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);


    notificationBuilder.setContentText("Download Finished");
    notificationBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);

    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Comment: cancel ongoing notification by using ID

Comment: notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);

Comment: I am seeing two notifications when downloading.When download completes it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same notification ID for all notifications you build within your AsyncTask, so that way each notification replaces the previous one. To get the behavior you are looking for, make the following change:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, values[0], false);
    //replace this line
    //notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
    //by this one
    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
```

Comment: Its working ,but displaying the progress is a problem for me.What should be the first parameter in publishProgress(Math.min(buffer.length, 100));   I know buffer.length is wrong

Comment: @abu That's another different question, you should ask as a new question

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two notifications generated because on your `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` you're using `1` as your `notification id`. Then in `onProgressUpdate()` you're using a variable `id` which is not shown what number its assigned to, might not be `1` so it generates 2 notifications since you invoke notify on two different `id`'s.